# GWT + Guava + JBoss: Class loader exception while dispatching incoming RPC call

Tags: exception, gwt, jboss, guava, rpc

I have set up a GWT application that is deployed to a JBoss server and (usually) performs as required. It is Maven based and divided into a server and a web module. Since I was recently introduced to the Guava library and due to its GWT compatibility I decided to include it in my project.

While trying to send an object of the Guava class Optional from the server to the web I unfortunately endure the following error message coming up on the jBoss console:

> Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call:
>
> com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract com.google.common.base.Optional com.company.project.client.rpc.ProjectService.getSearchWords(java.lang.String)' threw an unexpected exception:
>
> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "com.company.project.service.ProjectController.getSearchWords(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/common/base/Optional;"
>
> the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, com/company/project/server/ProjectServlet, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for resolved class, com/company/project/service/ProjectController, have different Class objects for the type va/lang/String;)Lcom/google/common/base/Optional; used in the signature

That's the line contained in the ProjectService.java file:

```
Optional<Set<String>> getSearchWords( String token );
```

And the analogue method signature in ProjectController.java (which is an interface for an ProjectControllerBean.java) looks the same.

This problem happens only in conjunction with the Guava class "Optional". Any other RPC method works well.

Does anybody have a clue what might be going on and how to fix that? I'd be really glad for any help!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1**

I guess it might have something to do with the fact that jboss provides an outdated version of the Guava library that is probably loaded through the ModuleClassLoader. But unfortunately I continuously fail to disable that automatism through a jboss-deployment-structure.xml :(

I put that file into src/main/application of my EAR with the following content:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.google.guava" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>

    <sub-deployment name="project-server.jar">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.google.guava" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: From what I can gather, the library you used to build the project has a different .class files for the same object.  Check that the jvm you built with is the same as the one the project is running on?  That would be my only guess, although that usually results in a bad version number exception.

Answer (score 0):

The `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` needs to be the in `META-INF` directory of the EAR. It should be in the `src/main/resources/META-INF` directory if your maven project.

Comment: According to this post (https://community.jboss.org/thread/172482) it does not have to be that directory. But I tried it as well and the problem still exists :( For some reason the module exclusion does not work properly. Adding dependencies (the jboss included Guava ones)  does have an effect on the other hand.

Comment: Ah, my mistake the locations I specified are needed for a WAR. Have you opened the EAR archive to verify that the jboss-deployment-structure.xml is in the META-INF directory?